# When did people learn that Columbus actually discovered a New World?

Tags: age-of-discovery, new-world, christopher-columbus

I know that Christopher Columbus never learnt that the land he discovered was actually a new continent. Until his death he thought that he reached Asia. There probably was a hypothesis in the very late 1400s and early 1500s that Columbus could reach a new world, not Asia. My question is: when did people actually agreed on the fact that Columbus discovered a new continent?

Comment: What research have you already done?

Comment: More or less. Thanks!

Comment: Do they agree though?  From the Chronicle of the City of Bristol: "This year, on St. John the Baptist's Day [24 June 1497], the land of America was found by the Merchants of Bristow in a shippe of Bristowe, called the Mathew".